# React useState array stays empty on first update

Tags: reactjs

```
const [liveRows, setLiveRows] = useState([]);

function addRow(arr){

    setLiveRows([...liveRows, arr]);

    console.log(liveRows)

}
```

When I run the addRow function with an array, the map used in the page re-renders fine, but the array in the log shows empty.

Running the function again shows the previous state of the array before the update, but the re-render shows correctly.

I am assuming this is due to the spread but am lost how to correct it?

Comment: `setState()` is usually asynchronous, which means that at the time you console.log the state, it's not updated yet.

Comment: extending on mc-user, `const [liveRows...` is a closure over the **current** state; and a *constant* on top of it. It will not show you the changes; it can't. But on the next render it will be a closure over the updated state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  setState is not an asynchronous! setState always work after the next render.

The **set** function only updates the state variable **for the next render.** If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value **that was on the screen before your call.**

For details : https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState

Comment: Thanks found the way around my issue from the link https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value